# Sorting and merge associative array (PHP)

Tags: php, associative-array

I have 2 associative arrays:

```
[0] => Array (
    [time] => 09:00:00
    [name] => To do something 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [time] => 09:30:00
    [name] => To do something 2
    )
[2] => Array (
    [time] => 10:00:00
    [name] => To do something 3
    )
```

and

```
[0] => Array (
    [time] => 09:00:00
    )
[1] => Array (
    [time] => 09:15:00
    )
[2] => Array (
    [time] => 09:30:00
    )
[3] => Array (
    [time] => 09:45:00
    )
[4] => Array (
    [time] => 10:00:00
    )
```

Need to do another associative array:

- if the field [time] in second array equals field [time] in first array then add [name];
- if field [time] in second array not equals field [time] in first array then add empty [name].

Should look like this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [time] => 09:00:00
    [name] => To do something 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [time] => 09:15:00
    [name] => 
    )
[2] => Array (
    [time] => 09:30:00
    [name] => To do something 2
    )
[3] => Array (
    [time] => 09:45:00
    [name] => 
    )
[4] => Array (
    [time] => 10:00:00
    [name] => To do something 3
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some puzzling I made it work for you.

This is the code you can use:

```
$array3 = array();

foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2){
    $found = false;

    foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1){
        if ($array1[$key2]['time'] == $array2[$key2]['time']) {
            $array3[$key2]['time']  = $array1[$key1]['time'];
            $array3[$key2]['name'] = $array1[$key1]['name'];
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$found){
        //add
        $array3[$key2]['time']  = $array2[$key2]['time'];
        $array3[$key2]['name'] = "";

    }
}

print_r($array3);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it shows only one last record [name] in the array and other elements in array show with empty [name] key, but I understood your idea. Thank you.